# SQLAlchemy Oracle: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have query generated by SQLAlchemy that is craeting long aliases. Is there a way to solve "ORA-00972: identifier is too long" from Python side?

Comment: Version?  Details? Example?

Answer (score 0):

What is the Oracle DB that you are using,  can you please send us the sample of the the query that you are using, maybe in the query you can create an alias which is less than the maximum length for the column name.